# How to infer template parameter "Func" from argument of constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17

My code and problems are as follows:

```
template <typename T, typename Func> class StepRange {
public:
  template <
      std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r_v<T, Func, const T &>, int> = 0>
  StepRange(T start, T stop, Func func)
      : start_(std::move(start)), stop_(std::move(stop)), val_(start),
        func_(std::move(func)) {}
  template <typename Step>
  StepRange(T start, T stop, Step step)
      : start_(std::move(start)), stop_(std::move(stop)), val_(start), 
        func_(std::function<T(const T &)>{
          [step](const T &val) { return val + step; }}) {}

private:
  T start_, stop_, val_;
  Func func_;
};

auto r = StepRange(1, 1, [](int val) { return val + 1;});
// since c++17 it works fine
auto t = StepRange(1, 1, 1);
// it does not compile and compiler says that it couldn't infer template argument 'Func'
```

So how can I use some additional methods to help compiler infer the type of 'Func'?

Comment: Aside: why wrap the lambda in `std::function`? You are using `start` after moving from it, why do you need `val_`?

Comment: @Caleth Thanks for pointing out that I don't need wrap the lambda in `std::function`. As for `val_`, that's context-decided, because the class `StepRange` is like a state machine and `val_` is needed to mark the status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is not able to deduce `Func` from your second constructor, so you need to tell it how to determine the `Func` class parameter when the first constructor is not viable. You can do that by adding a deduction guide:

```
template<typename T, typename Step, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_invocable_r_v<T, Step, const T &>, int> = 0>
StepRange(T, T, Step) -> StepRange<T, std::function<T(const T&)>>;
```

This will deduce `Func` to `std::function<T(const T&)>` whenever the first constructor is disabled.

Or, if you actually only want the second constructor to be used if the types of all three arguments match, then you can write instead

```
template<typename T>
StepRange(T, T, T) -> StepRange<T, std::function<T(const T&)>>;
```

Of course there are some edge cases to be considered in either case.

Comment: I won't know user-defined deduction guides without your answer! Thanks for you help!